# Kivy ScrollView exception raise Exception('ScrollView accept only one widget')

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Using the following code, after I input the information into the text boxes in my app, the offset_back returns a list and self.main, the id used in my .kv file to create a scrollview 
adds the layout but when I try to re-enter data a second time this happens:     "raise Exception('ScrollView accept only one widget')"

Do I need to reset self.main some way and if so how can I achieve this?
Thanks.

```
def set_back_offset(self):
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

     # catch empty box input which is a str, as Decimal will throw error.
    if self.initial_bet.text == str() or self.initial_odds.text == str():
        pop_warning().open()
     #make sure entered unicode text is numeric, if not throw pop-up warning
    elif not unicode.isnumeric(self.initial_bet.text) or not unicode.isnumeric(self.initial_odds.text):
            pop_warning().open()

    else:# all is good, create widgets
        for details in offset_back(Decimal(self.initial_bet.text), Decimal(self.initial_odds.text)):
            btn = Button(text=str(details[0]), size_hint_y=None, height=40,background_color= (255,0,0,1))
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        self.main.add_widget(layout)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the ScrollView is `self.main`?  The problem is presumably what it says on the tin, that it only accepts one widget and it already has a child when you try to add another one.

A simple fix would be to just first remove the existing widget with something like `self.main.remove_widget(self.main.children[0])`. However, if you want to replace them with something similar-looking you might be better off changing some properties of the existing widgets.

Either way, the solution is to remove the existing ScrollView child before adding a new one.

Comment: ,thanks, I understood the exception I just did not know how to remove child, it is my first time using any gui so all new to me.                                                                If I remove the child, nothing is returned to the screen. I am doing self.main.remove_widget(self.main.children[0]) after self.main.add_widget(layout). I thought it would  show the data then remove the child, am I incorrect?

Comment: You would need to remove the old child *before* adding the new one. I would have thought it would crash earlier than that though with your original description. Either way, keep following this general idea to fix the problem.

Comment: I saw my logic was backwards, I put self.main.remove_widget(self.main.children[0]) in the first line of the method but I am still getting the same exception. I will keep working along the lines you suggested and will figure it out, thanks again.